# Full text address matching

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, string-matching

I'm looking for duplicate records. I have a Property table with the fields street, number, city, state, county and zip. They get geo-coded based on location, but there are some holes in the data. Problem is if they make a simple typing error or omit certain fields, they won't come up as matches.

As of now a straight = comparison and LIKE aren't really doing a very good job. But Jaro Winkler and similar edit distance algorithms are running with extremely poor performance.

Comment: Yep, sounds about right.  Also take a look at levenshtein distance formula.  Implemented one of those for fuzzy string matching a couple years back.  Works great for matching up requests with existing data, but really needs human intervention.

Comment: If they are US addresses, you might be able to normalize them using USPS Address Standardization API: http://www.usps.com/webtools/address.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CASS-Certified Scrubbing Service](http://www.smartystreets.com/products/cass-certified-scrubbing) from [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com) offers deduplication as part of their address verification process.  Just upload the data in a delimited text file and the duplicates will be marked on the [output file](http://wiki.smartystreets.com/cass_certified_scrubbing_users_guide) you download.  There's always a free preview for each file you process so you don't have to purchase anything before you're satisfied with the results.  I'm a software developer for SmartyStreets and helped write the application.  I'm pretty pleased with both its functionality and ease of use.  We also have an [API](http://www.smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) you could use but the deduplication would be your responsibility (just compare the full, 12-digit Delivery Point Barcode, which serves as a unique identifier for addresses).